# Confirming if ArcGIS Online is down?

Tags: arcgis-online

If anyone is experiencing issues with ArcGIS Online, it may be down.

How can this be confirmed?

Comment: That's cloud computing... the underlying issue is amazon s3.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an IT issue that will be resolved soon.

Comment: This is the status page https://status.aws.amazon.com/

Comment: @GISKid Can you please give some examples of questions that have been posted as a result?

Comment: I think this is a fair question/concern so does ESRI they have a site for it.... you can check the status of arcgis services at https://status.arcgis.com/

Comment: @risail This question has pretty much zero lasting value, though. Once the issue is resolved, the answer will be, "No," until and unless it goes back down again. The answer is *very* dependent on time. A post dated 2017-02-28 is not going to help me determine if ArcGIS Online is down a year from now.

Comment: @jpmc26 when it goes down be it aws or some other issue it will...this site is a resource arguable no question has lasting value once you learn it. ESRI services will go down again the answer now shows you how to check and a possible check on the root cause (amazon) aws services go down more often then you may think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Confirmed on GeoNet:
https://geonet.esri.com/thread/191067-agol-down

May cause service interruptions. Can check here to see the latest status:
https://status.arcgis.com/

Comment: This is related to the current Amazon outage that has taken down many services that use AWS including Imgur (which hosts Stack Exchange images). http://www.usatoday.com/story/tech/news/2017/02/28/amazons-cloud-service-goes-down-sites-scramble/98530914/

Comment: UPDATE: "Due to the current issues on arcgis.com our planned maintenance this evening has been postponed to March 1st between 5pm and midnight PST. The issues currently affecting arcgis.com are due to infrastructure issues and are unrelated to our planned maintenance."

Comment: Another link for you: https://techcrunch.com/2017/02/28/amazon-aws-s3-outage-is-breaking-things-for-a-lot-of-websites-and-apps/.

Comment: Was also wondering if it could be due to the recent cloudflare breach as well http://www.sciencealert.com/here-s-what-you-need-to-know-about-the-massive-cloudbleed-data-breach